# Unity3d, when I touch an InputField, the keyboard doesn't show

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, input

[image: un opened keyboard]When I tap on an inputfield on android device, i get a little text area and an ok button. But I have to touch the input field to get the keyboard to pop up.

Any ideas?

All I'm doing code wise is:

```
if (!wasFocused && TouchScreenKeyboard.visible && createAccountPanel.activeSelf)
    {
        wasFocused = true;
        btnMat.color = validC;
    }else if (wasFocused && !TouchScreenKeyboard.visible && createAccountPanel.activeSelf) {
        wasFocused = false;
        btnMat.color = invalidC;
        //messageMNG.CreateMessage("Checking name: " + usernameChangeInput.text, true);
        dbMNG.CheckName(usernamePreview.text);
    }
```

When I do a check, it says that touchscreenkeyboard is visible.

**EDIT
I just created a new scene and added an input field and a text mesh pro input field and I get the exact same thing.

[image: Empty scene still broken keyboard]

Comment: Did you modify the InputField properties in any way via code or the inspector? Also, have you seen this on multiple devices?

Comment: edited question: All I'm doing is checking if keyboard is visible or not. it returns true. My suspicion is that i'ts not "active" but I can't access it like the docs suggest with touchscreenkeyboard.active.

Answer (score 3):

The keyboard does not pop up if you are running the app on Unity Remote app. Keyboard will automatically show up once you build and run your unity app on device.

Comment: Nope, Game is live in play store. (This isn't an ad) If you want to see it, Lexicube on Play store. Still happens on Pixel phones. I've never used Unity Remote.

Comment: @DKinnison try with the latest Unity 2018 version. I have tried adding a simple InputField and on clicking it, the keyboard pops up on my Pixel device as expected.

Comment: I'll try it for sure. I will be trying this in my next level major update. Thanks for following up!

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem today, but found the reason no keyboard was showing was due to building and launching onto a locked phone.  When I made sure the phone was unlocked when I clicked the input, the keyboard showed up below that box/ok portion.

Comment: Very interesting. I'll pass that along to Unity. We have narrowed it down to only Pixel and Pixel 2's. I'm awaiting an answer from them and will report back as soon as I have a solid answer! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Did you get any response from them yet?

Comment: Also seeing this on Pixel 3 :(

Comment: If others find this, I believe the OP reported the bug and looks like a fix may be in 2019.1: https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/android-keyboard-doesnt-open-when-an-inputfield-is-touched-with-android-api-level-28

Comment: Is there a work around/fix for 2018.3? I don't want to shift the whole project to 2019, and deal with any possible incompatibilities.

Comment: I heard back from Unity and they say that it's a known issue but only with Pixel Phones. I have my doubts.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue here on a Samsung S9+.